# CentOS 7 yum-cron - Out of memory: Kill process or sacrifice child

Tags: centos, yum, out-of-memory

I am on centos 7 hosted on a vps. The server would stay alive for a couple of days before everything gets killed by OOM. A restart fixes things, but it's a temporary fix.

The error (there is a full-page - see below): `c21t73 l446497 out of memory: kill process 16545 (yum-cr n) score 256 or sacrifice child`

[image]

Pritunl is an OpenVPN I am hosting on the server.

What is the possible cause (& solution) for this sort of thing?

I know the usual solution of a) disabling OOM or b) setting a higher limit or c) setting up a swap file.

I want to avoid those if possible because the VPS only has 512mb of ram and if an application does run of memory (due to OOM being disabled or the higher limit) the implications might be worse.

I also only 10 gb of mem and would like somewhat fast service so the swap file might affect speeds.

Thanks in advance & I am happy to provide more info if needed :)

Comment: What exactly is `pritunl` and why does it consume around 130 MiB of anonymous memory? There are separate `openvpn` processes listed in the output with much more appropriate memory consumption. Is `pritunl` perhaps a Python script or something?

Comment: The VPN is set up according to instructions [here](https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/1140511-diy-vpn-pritunl-setup-tutorial/). Pritunl is installed according to instructions [here](https://docs.pritunl.com/docs/installation). As far as I know it is the VPN not a python script. It shouldn't be an issue since no one has  brought up the issue on the forums. Ill also post this there.